# How to fix JavaScript promise using AWS SDK for S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, promise

Using JavaScript promise to upload a batch of files to an s3 bucket, the `.then()` function calls immediately after the `putObject()` function. How do I configure it to call when all files are successfully uploaded?

Below you can see the code that I have tried, most of which was from the AWS tutorial site.

```
var putBatch = function putBatch(bucket,folder, files) {
  // Make all the putObject calls immediately
  // Will return rejected promise if any requests fail
  return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
    var params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: folder +"/" + file.name,
      Body: file,
      Metadata: {
               latlng: "saf",
               timestamp: "fds",
               alt: "df",
               mission: "kjfahsdk"
             }
    };
    return s3.putObject(params).promise();
  }));
};

function addPhoto(albumName) {
  var fileBatch = [];
  var files = document.getElementById("inputGroupFile01").files;
  if (!files.length) {
    return alert("Please choose a file to upload first.");
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // console.log((files[i]));
    var file = files[i];
    var fileName = file.name;
    // var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName) + '//';
    var photoKey = albumName + "/" + fileName;
    fileBatch.push(file);
  }
  //putBatch(albumName, fileBatch);

  putBatch(albumBucketName,albumName, fileBatch)
  .then(console.log("done"))
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
}
```

As soon as I call the `putBatch()` function, I receive "done" in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use async for wait till file upload to s3 like:

```
var putBatch = function async putBatch(bucket,folder, files) {
  // Make all the putObject calls immediately
  // Will return rejected promise if any requests fail
  let result = await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
    var params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: folder +"/" + file.name,
      Body: file,
      Metadata: {
               latlng: "saf",
               timestamp: "fds",
               alt: "df",
               mission: "kjfahsdk"
             }
    };
    let s3Result = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
    return s3Result;
  }));
  return result;
};
```

Comment: This worked once i passed a function to `.then(data=>{ console.log(data)});`  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try  jQuery.when(). You can read more from [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when(putBatch(albumBucketName,albumName, fileBatch))
  .then(console.log("done"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input but this method has the same result as before, it is logging "done" before completion.